# Applying contour integration to $\int_{0}^{\pi}dx\frac{cos(x)}{\sqrt{x^2 + x_0^2}}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration

Is it possible to apply contour integration to find the value of following integral $$\int_{0}^{\pi}dx\frac{cos(x)}{\sqrt{x^2 + x_0^2}}$$

Comment: Part of the question is to guess what $\;f\;$ is? Further, what have you done so far?

Comment: If there was no square root, we can calculate residue. Not sure with square root.

Comment: I'm interested: How would you do this integral by residue method if the square is missing?

Comment: I think in that case if we multiply denominator by $(x-i x_0)$ and put $x = i x_0$ we can get the resultgs

Comment: But the domain of integration permitts the use of standard residue calculus...

Comment: A naive application of the standard method of converting it to a contour integral gives $\int_{|z| = 1}\frac{z + 1}{2\sqrt{4x_0^2 - (\log z)^2}}\frac{dz}{iz^{3/2}}$ which does not look very nice. There is also a problem related to the branch of the $\sqrt{}$ and $\log$ functions here. I don't think the integral has a solution in elementrary problem based on the simple fact that if we simplify it by removing the square root the solution will be in terms of the [cos integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html).

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{cos(x)}{\sqrt{x^2+x_0^2}}~dx ~=~ K_0\big(|x_0|\big),~$ see [Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) for more information. So I doubt that the integral you posted has any meaningful closed form expression.